# Serialize a collection of POJOs objects to JSON struct from Morphia / MongoDB in Java

Tags: java, json, mongodb, morphia

I am using Morphia (0.99) for mapping POJO to MongoDB (2.0.6). Now I want to return a collection / list as a JSON struct from my data-store with including IDs for each object to be sent with jQuery to the browser client.

I retrieve the POJO list from the data-store and then convert each object to a `DBObject` MongoDB object. This works fine except that the id of the object is not included in the print-out of the object. This could be due to the the ID is inherited from the Class A. The POJO B has a lot of property members, so one idea was to make a simple proxy POJO and then Serialize.

How can I make a JSON struct from the list of `DBObject`(with Morphia or MongoDB driver) and how can I include the `id` for each element in the struct?

PS. I've bean looking at the `BasicBSONList` MongoDB driver object or using the GSON (Google) lib, but I am lacking the pattern for how to do this.

POJO Classes

```
Class A {
    @Id
    private ObjectId id;
}

Class B extends A {
    ...

    @Override    
    public ObjectId getId() {
        return super.getId();
    }

    @Override
    public void setId(ObjectId id) {
        super.setId(id);
    }
    ...
}
```

Morphia /MongoDB Query

```
...
List<B> bList = bQry.asList();        
List<DBObject> dbObjList = Util.mapObjectToStringList((List<Object>)(List<?>)bList);
...

public static List<DBObject> mapObjectToStringList(List<Object> objList) {
    List<DBObject> dbObjectList = new ArrayList<DBObject>();
    Mapper mapper = morph.getMapper();        
    for(Object obj : objList) {
        DBObject dbObj = mapper.toDBObject(obj);
        Util.debug("Result as DB Object: " +dbObj.toString());
        dbObjectList.add(dbObj);
    }        
    return dbObjectList;
}
```

Comment: I'm looking for a 'clean' answer to this as well.

Comment: Good, hope someone has a solution. What version of Morphia are you using @Ankur ?

Comment: If you are storing data as JSON in mongodb, why convert to a Java object (DBObject) and convert back to JSON before sending to client ? Why not retrieve JSON from mongodb and send it directly to client ?

Comment: @brainOverflow That is what I thought was easy. Morphia is hiding the MongoDB BSON and Java object DBObject (binary representation of JSON) handling. I get Exceptions when trying to get the DBObject representation of my POJO objects. All my MongoDB query's are through Morphia to keep the code clean.